# Content type with a field of multiple values of other content type (1-n relation)

Tags: nodes

What should be the approach for the common cases where we need a content type with a field of multiple values of other content type? The typical "*1* invoice as *n* invoice lines" where *invoice* is a content_type and *invoice_line* other content type.
I did some research and I'm confused because there are: [Relation](http://drupal.org/project/relation), [References](http://drupal.org/project/references), [Entity References](http://drupal.org/project/entityreference)... 
(For Drupal 7)

Thank you.

Comment: Is there any special reason for using two content types for managing invoice ? Why dont you make it as a single node ?

Comment: Hi Nikhil, I just gave a well know example to illustrate the "1 to many" problem so everyone could better understand the question. Imagine that you want the sub content type to be also a node, so you can customize fields, have comments, tags, etc.
(But I understand your question because for this invoice example doesn't make much sense for an invoice line to be treated independently from the invoice itself)

Answer (score 1):

The [Entity reference](http://drupal.org/project/entityreference) would be the best choice for your requirement. It is also a successor of the [References](http://drupal.org/project/references) module.

> References will most probably be deprecated in the near future in
>   favor of Entity Reference, which should probably be considered first
>   on fresh D7 projects.

The [Relation](http://drupal.org/project/relation) module is more suitable for complex relationship. You can see this clearly in its module page:

> Relation is an API module and storage model for both simple and the
>   most complex relations between entities. The module can handle both
>   directional and symmetrical relations very well.
>
> Relations are entities and can therefore have fields. This makes
>   Relation the most flexible and powerful relation model out there.